# Google Cloud Dataflow - From PubSub to Parquet

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to write Google PubSub messages to Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Dataflow. The PubSub messages come into json format and the only operation that I want to perform is a transformation from json to parquet file.

In the official documentation I found a template provided by google that reads data from a Pub/Sub topic and writes Avro files into the specified Cloud Storage bucket (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#pubsub-to-cloud-storage-avro). The problem is that the template source code is written in Java, while I prefer to use the Python SDK.

These are the first tests I'm doing with Dataflow and Beam in general, and there's not a lot of material online to take a hint from. Any suggestions, links, guidance, piece of code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this documentation help? https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.WriteToParquet

Comment: Since you are looking for general advice, I can tell you that there is a PTtransform method called WriteToParquet() in Apache Beam and it is used to write to Parquet, [link](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.WriteToParquet).  In addition, Google provides this code which shows how to write to GCS reading fro PubSub, [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-dataflow#code_sample). So you could read your messages then, write then to a parquet file ( providing the schema) and finally store it in GCS. Did it help you?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much @AlexandreMoraes! I had seen the PTtransform method called WriteToParquet(), but I was looking for an example where they used it. The link to the code you sent me is a good place to start!

Comment: @fedex [Here](https://medium.com/@gruby/extracting-data-from-bigquery-table-to-parquet-into-gcs-using-cloud-dataflow-and-apache-beam-c63ce819b06a) this should be a good start for you with the method WriteToParquet(). When you are moving forward with your code you can post other questions and get more specific help. Meanwhile, can I summarise this information I shared as an answer in order to further contribute to the community?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes yes of course, It can certainly help for any other person working on a similar use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to further contribute to the community, I am summarising our discussing as an answer.

Since you are starting with Dataflow, I can point out some useful topics and advice:

1. The PTransform [WriteToParquet()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.11.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html#apache_beam.io.parquetio.WriteToParquet) builtin method in *Apache Beam* is very useful. It writes to a *Parquet* file from a *PCollection* of records. Also, in order to use it and write to a parquet file, you would need to specify the schema as indicated in the documentation. In addition, this [article](https://medium.com/@gruby/extracting-data-from-bigquery-table-to-parquet-into-gcs-using-cloud-dataflow-and-apache-beam-c63ce819b06a) will help you understand better how to use this method and how to write it in a Google Cloud Storage(GCS) bucket.
2. Google provides [this code](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-dataflow#code_sample) explaining how read messages from PubSub and write them into Google Cloud Storage. This QuickStart reads the message from PubSub and write the messages from each window to a bucket.
3. Since you want to read from PubSub, write the message to Parquet and store the file in a GCS bucket, I would advise you to do the following process as steps of your pipeline: *Read your messages, write to a parquet file and store it in GCS.*

I encourage you to read the above links. Then if you have any other question you can post another thread in order to get more specific help.

Comment: @fedex I have posted the answer, I would appreciate if you can accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: @FedericoBarusco are you able to run the pub/sub subscription to a parquet file for streaming jobs?
I am getting some issue while writing the stuff to the parquet

Comment: Were you able to run the streaming pipelines with output parquet files?